# Why does Emacs insert ^m at the end of every line

Tags: emacs

Why does Emacs insert ^m at the end of every line in my Linux environment?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Emacs Line Return and Windows, Unix, Mac, All That ^M ^J ^L](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_line_ending_char.html)

> Q: Why does emacs show ^M in a buffer?
>
> A: The “^M” is ASCII caret notation for unprintable Carriage return char (ASCII 13). If emacs shows that, it's probably because you have mixed characters of ^M and ^J and emacs cannot interpret them consistently as newlines.
>
> To fix it, call “set-buffer-file-coding-system”, then give one of: “mac”, “dos”, “unix”. Then, save the file. If that does not fix it, you can use find and replace to remove it manually.

Comment: As an addendum `C-x RET f` is the key chord for set-buffer-file-coding-system, so you can type that instead. I never remember it, though.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question has been resolved, but I wanted to mention that [Dos2Unix](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/) is a handy part of a toolkit for file operation between UNIX/DOS/Mac machines. It is an easy command-based approach for adding/removing OS-preferred line endings.

Comment: Emacs can handle all the newline varieties a file might contain, without needing to modify the file as Dos2Unix does. Possibly worth knowing for those poor benighted souls who don't use God's own editor, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic, but let me add some extra information.

- As described before Emacs is able to open file and display properly files with the 3 most popular line endings:

  - Unix style:    `LF`       : `0x0a`
  - DOS style:     `CR` `LF`  : `0x0d 0x0a`
  - Old Mac style: `CR`       : `0x0d`

Emacs will render the file properly and displays in the mode line left corner the line ending found.

However, if the file has a mix of line where some lines use one style and other lines use another style, then Emacs will display the terminating `CR` as `^M` which stands for Control-M corresponding to the value `0x0d` which is ASCII Carriage Return: `CR`.

There are several reason this can occur, ranging from misuse of editors or VCS line ending conversion.

One quick way to detect what lines differ from the other is to do this:

- keep a copy of the original file, say file-A
- use the `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` utilities to convert away from the line   ending it should be and back to the one it should be and store the result in file-B
- Use Emacs `ediff` facility to compare the 2 files.  It will show the lines that were not correct.

If the file is already inside a Git or Mercurial repo, just change the file then use Emacs built-in VCS support to see the change using `C-x v d`, select the file then type `=`.

You will see the lines that did not have the proper line ending in the old version of your file.

Answer (score 1):

I know it´s an old question,  but for the record, there are other reasons why ^M appears at the end of files. I just had the same problem. Here is what happened:

1. Every day I use the same text file on Emacs and never saw ^M. I use this file to take personal notes.
2. Last time I used the file I copied and pasted the contents of an e-mail I got on MS Outlook.
3. Today I opened the same old file and every single line had a ^M at the end, and all non-ASCII characters were replaced by strange codes like ???.

**How to fix it:**

Open the same file on VI (yes, I know, the archenemy) and search for characters that appear in a highlight color. On my terminal it is blue. Remove those characters and everything will work fine again on Emacs.

**Cause:**

The problem was caused by some strange quotation mark characters that came from Outlook. The funny thing is that Emacs does not show this problem until you reopen the file, making it hard for you to identify that your file has a problem right away.

Comment: I love how solving an Emavs problem involves using Vim. TAKE THAT, EMACS!

Comment: You can do the exact same thing in Emacs.  You can also globally replace them all with a simple `query-replace` command, normally bound to `M-%`.  Use `C-q C-m` to identify the carriage return and hit return to specify an empty string as the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Emacs in a primarily DOS/Windows environment, Emacs should correctly recognize the line-ending system and deal with it transparently.

You might see ^M suddenly appear in a file because it has been edited, perhaps with a script, that added lines with UNIX line-endings, and now lline endings are mixed.

You can fix these lines by adding ^M back onto them, save the file, kill the buffer, and re-open it. Now it should look normal, and say (DOS) as the encoding marking on the status line.

The regexp to look for is \([^^M]\)$ and replace with \1^M. Remember to use Ctrl-Q to 'quote' the Ctrl-M characters.